# How to access child elements of a TextSwitcher using view binding?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I'm using the [Android view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) to get an automatically generated binding class of my XML. In my XML definitions I'm using a `TextSwitcher` control with two child elements of the type `TextView`.

In code I access the child views of the `TextSwitcher` like this:

```
...
_binding = MyViewBinding.inflate((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this, true);

((TextView)_binding.myTextSwitcher.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(_mySpecialColor);
((TextView)_binding.myTextSwitcher.getChildAt(1)).setTextColor(_mySpecialColor);
...
```

**Is there an easier way to access the child views of the `myTextSwitcher` directly with the `MyViewBinding` class without the need to cast them?**

The XML definitions looks like this:

```
<TextSwitcher
  android:id="@+id/myTextSwitcher"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TextSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the time I was searching at the wrong location in the generated binding class.

Those `TextView`'s are there directly accessible on my `_binding` variable.

```
// this does work
_binding.text1.setTextColor(_headerLabelColor);
_binding.text2.setTextColor(_headerLabelColor);
```

I thought they need to be accessible as child's of my `TextSwitcher` but it seems I learned something now.

```
// this does not work but I expected it to
_binding.myTextSwitcher.text1.setTextColor(_headerLabelColor);
_binding.myTextSwitcher.text2.setTextColor(_headerLabelColor);
```